# Multiple Controller routed to the same page AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, router

I'm trying to use AngularJS in my website and I ran into the following problem. I've seen it other places, but no answers that really satisfy my question.
I am attempting to access data from two controllers on the same page but nothing seems to be working. I am able to reach the data from one controller, and I'm able to access data from another one, but not both on the same page at the same time. They are both being accessed through the same app.

Here's my code:

```
'use strict';

castitApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/post/', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
                    controller: 'PostController',
                    resolve:{
                        resolvedPost: ['Post', function (Post) {
                            return Post.query();
                        }]
                    },
                    access: {
                        authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                    }
                })
            $routeProvider
                .when('/views/main.html', {
                    templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
                    controller: 'PostController',
                    resolve:{
                        resolvedPost: ['Post', function (Post) {
                            return Post.query();
                        }]
                    },
                    access: {
                        authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                    }
                })
});
```

route_employee.js

```
castitApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/employees.html', {
                templateUrl: '/employee-place.html',
                controller: 'EmployeeController',
                resolve:{
                    resolvedEmployee: ['Employee', function (Employee) {
                        return Employee.get('stephen', 'name');
                    }]
                },
                access: {
                    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                }
            })

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
                controller: 'EmployeeController',
                resolve:{
                    resolvedEmployee: ['Employee', function (Employee) {
                        return Employee.get('stephen', 'name');
                    }]
                },
                access: {
                    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                }
            })
    });
```

main.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
   <td ng-click="get(employee.personnelNum, 'employeesof')">
{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}
   </td>
</tr>
</table></center>   
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="post in posts">
    {{post.text}}
 </li>
```

There's another class called Employee that is essentially identical to the Post class in terms of its format, with changed keywords. I've found if I change the order of imports for the javascript files it alters which one works. Also, if I change the name in **.when('name'** on the one that works to a dummy name, the other will start working. It seems like I can't use two controllers, and I've heard directives may be the workaround but I'm very unclear on how to actually implement it.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: It seems like the one page is overwriting the other page with the template, which is where the problem really lies. If I make the template URL from the router null the page isn't printed with ngview, though.

Comment: have you tried using the attribute `ng-controller="secondController"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came up with the answer. It did have to do what Gavin mentioned with ng-controller, but I was having trouble accessing my controllers using the tags for a while now. I knew that was the right direction but I didn't know how to make my particular situation work.

It turns out that I needed to bypass routers entirely, instead of running things through them, and as far as I can tell there isn't a way to route two controllers to the same URL using the routeprovider. Instead of passing the resolved variable to my data as I had been doing, I am calling a service query directly from my Employee object. The fix was pretty much as simple as eliminating the code pointing to the main URLs in the router and then adding

```
$scope.employees = Employee.get('stephen', 'name');
```

in place of

```
$scope.employees = resolvedEmployee;
```

This resolved the "unknown provider" errors I was receiving when I tried to use ng-controller. Ultimately, those turned out to be the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'controllerAs' on route definition to differentiate them, like this:

```
castitApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/post/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostController',
                controllerAs: 'viewPost',
                resolve:{
                    resolvedPost: ['Post', function (Post) {
                        return Post.query();
                    }]
                },
                access: {
                    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                }
            })
        $routeProvider
            .when('/views/main.html', {
                templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
                controller: 'PostController',
                controllerAs: 'mainPost',
                resolve:{
                    resolvedPost: ['Post', function (Post) {
                        return Post.query();
                    }]
                },
                access: {
                    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
                }
            })
});
```

and in the view use {{ mainPost.something }} or {{ viewPost.something }}

For more information, check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Would this resolve an issue with two **different** controllers pointing to the same .when("" location?

Comment: You'll have two controllers into the same page, but with a different alias.